# Visual Studio Code highlight warring c c++

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, warnings

I've got confused about how to configure `VS Code` to show warnings, in my system:

- `C/C++` IntelliSense, debugging (installed)
- PROBLEMS windows is working fine, it quickly shows errors like identifier undefined vars and others.
- The following code doesn't show any warning:

// C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a;
    printf("%d", a);
  
}
```

In this case, I should get: `'a'` is used uninitialized, how I can get all warnings?

Comment: Yes, as stated in the question, the code _is_ supposed to flag warnings from the compiler. The question is why VS Code does not display them.

Comment: I don't use VS Code, and can't find a previous question. Did you explore the menus for "compiler options"? Spend half an hour browsing through the menus.

Comment: In VS IDE you can select properties then under `C/C++` property you can set the warning level. On the command line you can directly use the switches from `/W0` (no warnings) to `/W4` or `/Wall` for pedantic level.

Comment: Frankie, sorry  I am using Visual Studio Code, and your advice is for Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer,
Add "-Wall" in the file task.json located in the folder .vscode If the file task.json is not automatically generated by VS Code you can add it manually:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-Wall",
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

[image]

Comment: That does not seem to work for me